# Backbone Model fetch steps on loading indicator in Chrome & IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js

We have an app that shows a loading.gif while fetching a models data via backbone. The code pretty much looks like:

```
$('.loading-indicator').show()
myModel.fetch({async: false}) 
setSomeOtherVar = Date.today() //some var unrelated to fetch
$('.loading-indicator').hide()
```

This works fine in FFX, but in Chrome and IE the loading indicator disappears when fetch is called.  I can see this by stepping through w/ the debugger.  If i set a breakpoint on the fetch the indicator is there, and disappears immediately when the fetch is called.  The fetch is successful and there are no errors in console.

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think there is enough info here to give an answer. Could be that your container is loader is being removed with new data or a z-index issue.  You might have better luck binding to the fetch success method.

Comment: thanks for your response im_benton, but to clarify issue is not that the loading indicator doesn't clear, it's that the fetch call hides it for some reason.  For example if i set a breakpoint at line 1 of above code i see loading indicator.  upon executing line 2 the loading indicator is no longer visible

Comment: @d-coded: im facing this same issue...did you solve this issue???

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this and it works for me. i removed the `{async: false}`and it solved for me. As mentioned by @Alexander Derck, try removing the asynchronous and it should work.