# The .css() style before the backbone fetch does not work-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I'm trying to show a loading icon on click of a link, so that the users are aware that the app is loading. I'm applying it this way:

```
var list = new List();
$("#link").on("click",function(){
   $("#cont").css("opacity", 0.4); // to grey out the background area
   $("#loading").css({"display": "block"});
   list.fetch({
       //do something here
    });
 }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dfvxg5qz/1/

However, the page does not show the loading icon nor does it grey out as per the opacity style. I debugged to see where was the issue, I found out that only when i try to fetch something the .css() property does not get applied, else if i just render a page or do a backbone save, the .css property is applied and shoes the loading icon.
I'm not sure whats going on, or if there is any other way I can show the loading sign on click before the fetch happens.
i found a question on the stackoverflow very similar to what im facing:

[Backbone Model fetch steps on loading indicator in Chrome & IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605287/backbone-model-fetch-steps-on-loading-indicator-in-chrome-ie)

but doesnt look like its been solved, so still stuck at that...
Any ideas how to achieve this??
Thanks~

Comment: Your fiddle is non-functional/doesn't provide much value in this context. All I can add is that you are missing a `)` at the very end of your example snippet in the question. Make sure you're using a proper JS linter.

Comment: Also, this question doesn't appear to relate to Backbone, but to jQuery (in particular: a click handler that will leverage the `.css` jQuery function in its callback). You may consider rewording your question.

Comment: I think @MatthewVita is right in that you are not showing us enough for us to be able to debug anything. It sounds like perhaps fetch triggers an event that calls a method that removes the loading indicator, but who knows when we have so little to go on..

Comment: I would make a class called "loading", and then do a  `$(this).addClass('loading')` before the fetch, and a `$(this).removeClass('loading')` in the success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle I see this:

```
render: function(){
    $("#link").on("click",function(){
        $("#cont").css("opacity", 0.4); // to grey out the background area
        $("#loading").css({"display": "block"});
        getdata();
    });
},
```

In Backbone, the `render()` function is normally executed after the data fetched from the server,so I suggest that you should user `on` approach in your `initailize` function, just try this:

```
initialize: function(){  
        this.template = lisTmpl;
        $("#link").on("click",function(){
        $("#cont").css("opacity", 0.4); // to grey out the background area
        $("#loading").css({"display": "block"});
        getdata();
    });
},
```

In addition, you should not rewrite `render()` function in general, or the template may not be rendered successful! If you need to add function after render, I recommend plugin of Backbone named Marionette, which provides many callback function, such as `onRender`, just see this:
http://marionettejs.com/

Comment: i tried this:http://jsfiddle.net/dfvxg5qz/2/ but unfortunately the event is not listening the click on the link when i set it in initialize:() i set a debugger and it never stops at the debugger on click...is there any other way i could handle this situation..Thanks!

Comment: In your code ,you should use script to import backbone.js first! and initialize() function is executed when you initialize the Object create from backbone. I think you should learn how to use backbone.js first, just look here:http://backbonejs.org/